# Replace future months forecast with moving average python

Tags: python, pandas, time-series, moving-average, forecast

I have a dataframe in pandas in the below format

```
        Date        Value
0       2006-01     17.45
1       2006-02     18.23
2       2006-04     16.79
3       2006-05     17.98
...     ...     ...
166     2019-11     37.89
167     2019-12     36.34
```

I want to forecast *5 year future* values such that the forecasts are equal to the **10 year rolling average** for that particular month.
For instance, the forecast value for **2020-01** will be the average of the past 10 years **[2010, 2019]** of **January** values.

Important thing to note is that for the forecast of **2021-01**, the average should be calculated on data from **[2011,2020]** for January month i.e. the previous forecasted value for *2020-01* will be used as well.

```
        Date        Value
0       2020-01     15.6
1       2020-02     12.3
2       2020-04     14
3       2020-05     18
...     ...     ...
166     2025-11     37
167     2025-12     36
```

How can it be achieved efficiently in pandas?
Regards